# How to format date in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to display date like Wednesday, 5th May, 2011
I am trying

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(
                         current-date(),
                         '[FNn,*-3], [D01] [MNn,*-3] [Y0001]',
                         'en',
                         '',
                         'US'
                      )" />
```

And another one i tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(
                         current-date(),
                         '[FNn], [MNn] [D1o], [Y]',
                         'en',
                         (),
                         ()
                      )" />
```

Both gives me following. I need text and it gives number only. I use XSLT 2.0

```
3, 5 4, 2011
```

Comment: I know you're using XSLT2 but eventually it could be done in XSLT1: http://geekswithblogs.net/workdog/archive/2007/02/08/105858.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(
                                 current-date(),
                                 '[FNn], [D1o] [MNn,*-3], [Y]',
                                 'en',
                                 (),
                                 ()
                              )" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
Wednesday, 4th May, 2011
```

Tested on Saxon and Altova.

Comment: i have following declaration at Top <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

  <xsl:output method="xhtml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

Comment: @jatin: That shouldn't affect the result.